# Continuity of $x\mapsto \int_0^1 \frac{f(x, y)}{\sqrt y} dy$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, continuity

Let $ f : [0,1]^2 \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be bounded and such that $f(x,\cdot)$ is continuous for all $x$ and $f(\cdot,y)$ is continuous for all $y$. Show that $g$ defined by
$$ g(x) = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{f(x,y)}{\sqrt y}dy $$ 
is continuous on $[0,1]$.

Comment: Got it! hint from the another question with the same title, keeping the question posted, incase any one is interested.

Comment: It's just the DCT, right?

Comment: Yes, DCT using the fact that f is bounded.

Answer (score 1):

It suffices to prove that if $x\in[0,1]$ and $\left(x_n\right)_{n\geqslant 1}$ is a sequence with converges to $x$, then the sequence    $\left(g\left(x_n\right)\right)_{n\geqslant 1}$ converges to $g\left(x\right)$. To this aim, define $h_n\colon y\mapsto f\left(x_n,y\right)\cdot y^{-1/2}$. Since $f$ is bounded, the quantity $\sup_n\sup_{y\in[0,1]}\left|h_n\left(y\right)\right|$ is bounded. Moreover, for any $y\in(0,1]$, by continuity of $u\mapsto f(u,y)$, we derive that $h_n\left(y\right)\to f\left(x,y\right)y^{-1/2}$. We then conclude by dominated convergence.

Comment: thanks, i was thinking the same!!